# Error when making a GET request to Facebook using Facebook's PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've been trying to work out how to send a Facebook notification using their latest PHP SDK for almost a week now, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried everything I could find online but I keep running into errors.
So I decided to try a simple GET request using PHP instead.
To do this I'm trying to use the sample code Facebook gives here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0

This is the code I'm trying:
(I've replaced my App ID and App Secret here)

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('123456789', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9');
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, '123456789|a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9', 'GET', '/me');

// OR
//$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(/* . . . */);
//$request = $fb->request('GET', '/me');

// Send the request to Graph
try {
  $response = $fbApp->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'User name: ' . $graphNode['name'];
?>
```

This isn't working, it's giving me the error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookApp::getClient() in **/home/mywebsite/public_html/Games/Barre/phptest.php** on line **15**

I don't understand what's wrong, I think I'm following Facebook's documents correctly, but it's not working. It seems to be saying that `getClient()` isn't included in the `facebook-sdk-v5` files I've included at the start. I've made sure that I'm pointing to the correct directory for the files and they're all present and correct in that folder (`facebook-sdk-v5`). Can anyone here can see where I'm going wrong?

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to solve this. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

//    $fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('123456789', 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9');
//    $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, '123456789|a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9', 'GET', '/me');

// OR

 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{123456789}',
  'app_secret' => '{a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  'default_access_token' => '{123456789|a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9}',
  ]);

$request = $fb->request('GET', '/me');

// Send the request to Graph
try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'User name: ' . $graphNode['name'];
?>
```

Error in console:

> Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token signature

**2nd UPDATE**

This code is working correctly:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php'; 

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{123456789}',
  'app_secret' => '{a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  ]);

$request = $fb->post('/USERIDGOESHERE/notifications', array( 'template' => 'This is a test notification!'), '123456789|a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j');

?>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error.

Comment: Hi @JonStirling thanks for your reply, I'm not sure what you mean, the error that it says is on line 15 is referring to ``getClient()`` on line 13 in the above code (I moved the bottom half of my code up by two lines when I was formatting it for this question, so while the error says line 15, it's referring to line 13 above, but the code is exactly the same as what I'm trying.

Comment: In the code provided, you don't have an `$fb` variable (uncommented), so you would get a different error. Going by the error, compared to your code it looks like your actual code looks more like `$fbApp->getClient()` since that would produce the error you're seeing.

Comment: Hi again @JonStirling you're completely right, the code I'm testing has ``$fbApp->getClient()`` instead of ``$fb->getClient()`` there because I'm using lines 4 and 5 instead of lines 8 and 9. The code I took from Facebook's example uses ``$fb->getClient()``. I've updated my question to correct this, thanks for letting me know, do you have any idea why the error is appearing?

Comment: Yes, because the `FacebookApp` class doesn't have a `getClient` method, `Facebook` does.

Comment: Make sure you are actually using v5 of the SDK. v4 was quite short-lived, but I think they used the same github repro for v5.

Comment: Hi @JonStirling thanks for explaining that, I've changed my code and it seems to have gotten past that part, but now it's showing another error. I was unsure of what to put in the parenthesis on line 8 (it's blank in Facebook's documents) so I put my AppID and secret again, but it's now saying that I need to pass an array. Could you take a look at the update I've made at the bottom of my question? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @CBroe thanks for your comment. I downloaded v5 directly from the green button on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted is that the correct version?

Comment: @Emily see [these docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0) for constructing the `Facebook` class.

Comment: Hi @JonStirling thanks for that link, I've updated my question again to show my current attempt, but I'm a little confused by something. I watched this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xt-ZRuAVekU and thought that joining the AppID and App Secret together (separated by a ``|``) would work as an App Access token, however when I try to do this I get the following error: ``Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token signature`` Could you take a look at my update again and see if it's the wrong way to set the ``default_access_token``?

Comment: It talks about how to set and get the access token here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0 but I'm not sure about how to fit that into my code correctly, or if it's the right way to get the access token I need. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Emily I couldn't say regarding `default_access_token`, but it doesn't look like that's a required bit of data anyway so if you don't actually need it, I'd get rid of it. Another thing I notice is that you've left the `{` and `}`s around some of your values, have you done that in your actual code?

Comment: Hi @JonStirling I've mixed code from the youtube tutorial above and Facebook's docs, and it's now working. I'm able to send a user a notification using this code, but I think it looks very short and I'm not sure if it's safe or correct. Would you be able to look at it and see if it's correct? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @CBroe I've managed to get some code to work, but I'm not sure if I'm using v5 PHP code, I'm worried it might be older code and might not work for long, would you be able to tell me if I'm using old/soon to be depreciated code? It's under the "2nd UPDATE" heading. Thanks for your time.